# Facebook Messenger Bot Framework images

Tags: facebook, botframework

I have a bot that is running on both Skype and Facebook, hero and thumbnail cards sent to Skype appear as expected but on Facebook the image is stretched and scaled to fit the size of the card.

How can i stop Facebook doing this as its undesirable?

Comment: Did you set the image width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Facebook messenger there are 2 sizes possible. 'Horizontal' which has a 1.91:1 ratio and 'Square' which has a 1:1 ratio. The 'Horizontal' option is the default value.

When creating a Hero or thumbnail card using the classes provided in the framework this value can not be set. If you want to set this value you will have to implement your own model and pass your own json back.

Check out the documentation for Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template).